# Digitizer calibration or hardware issue?

Tags: hardware, touchscreen, calibration, samsung-galaxy-tab-a

I recently obtained a new galaxy tab A and have been noticing that touching small buttons in certain places is particularly hard (specifically the "read more" button in youtube comments).

After doing some experimenting with the developer options that show touch information, I found that the touch screen didn't want to register touches in vertical lines all across the screen. In particular, when swiping diagonally the registered line meanders to avoid moving horizontally then jumps across to follow my finger, like I'm pulling it across a washboard. Two lines in particular at dx 331.7/332.7 and dx 943.2/944.2 seem to catch the pointer like a cliff.

**Is this a software/firmware issue?** Or is this digitizer screwy despite being new? Can this be fixed with a factory reset, or not installing a recent patch, or updating firmware?

I've seen this behavior in an older tablet (Memo pad 8) but much worse, so much so that tapping on one of these lines would register a tap on either side of the vertical line, and scrolling would often create double taps. That issue manifested while playing a rhythm game, so I assumed some hardware cracked.

Comment: As it is a new device, perform a factory reset and test it again. If the result is still the same return the device back to the vendor as a hardware defect is very likely.